# Firebase Firestore - order collection by timestamp with where clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to sort a collection data by timestamp (date field's type is timestamp in Firetore) as below:

```
postsSnap = await _firebaseFirestore
        .collection(Paths.posts)
        .where('review', isNotEqualTo: '')
        .orderBy('review')
        .where('content', isEqualTo: contentRef)
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .limit(limit)
        .get();
```

But when I print the docs date value, it looks like there are not ordered by date field. Results are as following:

```
flutter: 2020-08-25 13:45:01.552
flutter: 2021-03-30 09:19:52.138
flutter: 2020-06-27 00:18:44.615
flutter: 2020-07-01 04:57:53.645
flutter: 2021-03-25 14:06:30.692
flutter: 2020-05-28 11:49:07.180
flutter: 2020-05-30 22:02:54.650
flutter: 2021-06-08 02:41:28.650
flutter: 2020-05-31 08:49:35.456
flutter: 2020-05-31 06:38:25.894
```

The index is also created:

[image]

I wonder if I am missing something while using the where clause in queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call:

```
.orderBy('review')
```

It means that you order the results ascending according to the `review` field. When you add an additional call to:

```
.orderBy('date', descending: true)
```

It means that your order the above results by `date` **only** when two or more reviews are the same. So the best option that you have is to remove the first orderBy by call and do the first ordering on the client.

Comment: I added `orderBy('review')` call because of `isNotEqualTo` where clause. if I remove it, the query gives an error. If I remove all `review` conditions (where and orderBy), then I am not sure how I am going to paginate this query because it will return empty reviews also. So I think i have to add additional queries to if there are empty reviews, right?

Comment: Or you can create separate collections for reviews that are empty and for the ones that are not empty. In this way, you'll only need a single order, by date, right?

Comment: hey @alex-mamo, I found a better way to this, I just added a new field which is called 'hasReview' in boolean type, then I remove all 'review' conditions and only added `.where('hasReview', isEqualTo: true)` condition, now it is working fine, thanks for you help. I accepted this answer as a solution because this explains how multiple orderBy works in firebase firestore

Answer (score 0):

First save the timestamp field as a Unix timestamp and then sort it.

You can convert datetime to timestamp as

```
var timestamp =  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

And from timestamp to datetime as

```
var dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: When i remove ".where('review', isNotEqualTo: '').orderBy('review')" part from query, the order of docs are correct. Can be the issue related to where clause part? Because the date field is already saved as a timestamp in firebase.

Comment: I just tested if this is going to work, but unfortunately, this issue is not related if the date is timestamp, or milliseconds.

Comment: Oh okay, 
then try this...
postsSnap = await _firebaseFirestore
        .collection(Paths.posts)
        .where('review', isGreaterThan: '')
        .orderBy('review', descending: false)
        .where('content', isEqualTo: contentRef)
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .limit(limit)
        .get();

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Have you created indexes of firestore?

Comment: Yes, you can see the screenshot in question

Comment: No, I mean, the indexes of firestore,
please try to run your firestore query into try catch and print the error... You'll get a link of your indexes to create index. you must have to create index first in firestore before adding more then one query filters.
more on indexes
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: The index is already created (you can see the screenshot of the index in question), I created it by the using link in error as you said.